# how to make a gridview column fill down instead of horziontally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

i need to make the messages column of my gridview a certain width and when the text exceeds that width it must fill down so it does not extend the width of the overall gridview off the page.

here is my code so far...

```
      <div class="LeftMessages">
          <h1> Whats new </h1>
          <p> 
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Your message "></asp:Label> 
           <asp:TextBox ID="MessageTB" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:Button ID="MessageBut" runat="server" Text="Post" 
                  onclick="MessageBut_Click" /> 
          </p>


    <p>
    <asp:GridView ID="MessagesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="DeleteRow"
    DataKeyNames="MessageId" Width="100%">

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#226FAA" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Double" BorderColor="#226FAA"/>
    <RowStyle BorderStyle="Double" BorderColor="#226FAA" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#77ACD4" />

    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User" ReadOnly="True"/>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
       <ItemStyle Wrap="false" Width="20px" />
      <ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("Message")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("Message")%>
      </ItemTemplate>

 try this

  <ItemTemplate>
 <div style="max-height:20px;">
  <%# Eval("Message")%>
 <div>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work, thank you for your solution however

Comment: can you show the screen shot or the html generated in browser of this part

Comment: im not sure if i can but ill try

Answer (score 0):

give the rows and columns value of multiline text box

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: there is property of rows and columns for multiline textbox , just see in intelligence list

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID ="TXT" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" columns="25" />

Comment: Thanks, however it is not the textbox i want to validate its the actual column that the textbox enters its information into

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
 <div style="width:200px;"max-height:100px;Overflow:scroll">
  <%# Eval("Message")%>
 <div>
  </ItemTemplate>

Comment: if it doest not work, i would suggest you to take a literal to bind the message, and then fix the width of literal

Answer (score 0):

Apply a proper css class to that column, eg:

```
<ItemStyle CssClass="column"/>
```

and in your css declare that class as:

```
.column{
   width: 20px;
   max-width: 20px;
}
```

Obviously, change the given value of 20px to any which suits your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately this also didnt work. Isnt there any way of making a column automatically move to the next line?

Comment: For sure you can't. Gridview are rendered as HTML tables, so you definitely can't shift a column on the next row (without heavy client-side scripting). You may play with css property "overflow:hidden" and text ellipsis to avoid a column to become too large.